# Similar Triangle drawn on concurrent cevians

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, triangles

> In $\triangle ABC$, $\overline{AA'}, \overline{BB'}$ and $\overline{CC'}$ are concurrent cevians. Points $D,E,F$ are on $\overline{AA'}, \overline{BB'}$ and $\overline{CC'}$ respectively (as in the diagram below) such that $\triangle DEF \approx \triangle ABC$. Prove that the sides of $\triangle DEF$ are parallel to the sides of $\triangle ABC$ respectively or show that this is not the case always.

[image]
Note that the points $D,E,F$ are between the vertices of $\triangle ABC$ and the point of contact of the cevians.

This is what I tried :

If $DE \| AB$, then $\frac{PD}{PA} = \frac{PE}{PB} = \frac{DE}{AB}$

If $DF \| AC$, then $\frac{PD}{PA} = \frac{PF}{PC} = \frac{DF}{AC}$

If $EF \| BC$, then $\frac{PE}{PB} = \frac{PF}{PC} = \frac{EF}{BC}$

Equating all $3$ equations yields $\frac{DE}{AB} = \frac{DF}{AC} = \frac{EF}{BC}$, which is true (as the triangles are similar). Thus the line segments are parallel.

Is this proof correct? Are there any counter cases that disproves this proof?

**Help is appreciated!**

Comment: "parallels"  are the expected result and you are using it as given.

Comment: I tried to solve the problem backwards. If the lines were parallel, we get such-and-such results. This is true. Thus the lines are parallel. That's the doubt I wanted to clear on whether it could be proved in such a fashion, and if no, is there any case which disproves my proof?

Comment: Assuming ALL the consequences as given (so called backward proof) is not allowed in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial condition: In $\triangle ABC$, cevians AA’, BB’, and CC’ meet at P. D is a point on AP.

[image]

Through D, draw DF // AC cutting CC’ at F. Similarly draw DE // AB cutting BB’ at E. Join EF.

The first question is “will $\triangle DEF \sim\triangle ABC$?”

Note that, after the construction, we have $\triangle PAC \sim \triangle PDF$ and this yields $\dfrac {PF}{PC} = \dfrac {PD}{PA}$. Similarly, we have $\dfrac {PE}{PB} = \dfrac {PD}{PA}$.

Then, $\dfrac {PF}{PC} = \dfrac {PE}{PB}$. This means $\triangle PEF \sim \triangle PBC$ because $\angle BPC$ is the common angle. Therefore, $\angle PEF= \angle PBC$ and $\angle PFE=\angle PCB$. By AAA, $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle DEF$. In fact, the $\triangle DEF$ so constructed is the only triangle meeting the given condition.

Finally, EF // BC, a result already obtained in the last paragraph.

---

Further explanation:

For a particular point D on AP. The lines DE an DF so constructed fixed $\angle EDF$ to match $\angle BAC$.

[image]

To simply the picture drawing, we let $\angle BAC = 90^0$. For similarity to occur, we need $\angle EDF = 90^0$ also, so that D is against A.

$\triangle DEF$ is then constructed according to way suggest above.

Suppose there is another triangle $DE’F’ $ constructed with (1) E’ on BP; (2)F’ on PC and $\angle E’DF’ = \angle EDF = \angle BAC = 90^0$.

BY considering $\triangle DFX$ and $\triangle DF’X$, we can see that $\angle DF’X \ne \angle DFX = \angle ACB$. This means $\triangle DE’F’$ so constructed will never be similar to $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: > "In fact, the △DEF so constructed is the only triangle meeting the given condition."

How can we prove this is true?

Comment: @infixint943 see further explanation added.